# Alias templates used in SFINAE lead to a hard error

Tags: c++, typedef, sfinae, type-traits, class-template

I want to use an enabler (an alias template of `enable_if`), defined in one class template, in another class template. It looks like this:

```
template< ... > using enabler = typename std::enable_if< ... >::type;
```

This works fine for SFINAE. But when I add another alias template in the second class like

```
template< ... > using enabler
    = typename first_class<..> :: template enabler< ... >;
```

and use this enabler for SFINAE, substitution (correctly) fails but with a hard error for g++4.8.0 and 4.8.1. clang++3.4 gives only a soft error and SFINAE works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

#include <cstdlib>

template< typename T >
class A
{

    struct B {};

public :

    struct U : B {};

    template< typename D, typename R = void >
    using enable_if_is_B = typename std::enable_if< std::is_base_of< B, D >::value, R >::type;

    template< typename D, typename R = void >
    using enable_if_is_not_B = typename std::enable_if< !std::is_base_of< B, D >::value, R >::type;

    template< typename D >
    auto
    operator () (D const &) const
    -> enable_if_is_B< D >
    {
        std::cout << "D is B" << std::endl;
    }

    template< typename D >
    auto
    operator () (D const &) const
    -> enable_if_is_not_B< D >
    {
        std::cout << "D is not B" << std::endl;
    }

};

template< typename T >
struct B
{

    using A_type = A< T >;

    template< typename D, typename R = void >
    using enable_if_is_B = typename A_type::template enable_if_is_B< D, R >;

    template< typename D, typename R = void >
    using enable_if_is_not_B = typename A_type::template enable_if_is_not_B< D, R >;

    template< typename D >
    auto
    operator () (D const &) const
    -> enable_if_is_B< D >
    {
        std::cout << "D is B!" << std::endl;
    }

    template< typename D >
    auto
    operator () (D const &) const
    -> enable_if_is_not_B< D >
    {
        std::cout << "D is not B!" << std::endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
    using T = struct Z;
    using A_type = A< T >;
    using U = typename A_type::U;
#if 0
    using X = A< T >;
#else
    using X = B< T >;
#endif
    X const x;
    x(0);
    x(U());
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Which with `#if 1` produces:

```
D is not B
D is B
```

But for `using X = B< T >;` generates an error on g+4.8.0:

```
<stdin>: In substitution of 'template<class T> template<class D, class R> using enable_if_is_B = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<A<T>::B, D>::value, R>::type [with D = int; R = void; T = main()::Z]':
<stdin>:48:73:   required by substitution of 'template<class T> template<class D, class R> using enable_if_is_B = typename B<T>::A_type::enable_if_is_B<D, R> [with D = int; R = void; T = main()::Z]'
<stdin>:55:2:   required by substitution of 'template<class D> B<T>::enable_if_is_B<D> B<T>::operator()(const D&) const [with D = D; T = main()::Z] [with D = int]'
<stdin>:82:5:   required from here
<stdin>:18:91: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, void>'
<stdin>: In substitution of 'template<class T> template<class D, class R> using enable_if_is_not_B = typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_base_of<A<T>::B, D>::value), R>::type [with D = A<main()::Z>::U; R = void; T = main()::Z]':
<stdin>:51:81:   required by substitution of 'template<class T> template<class D, class R> using enable_if_is_not_B = typename B<T>::A_type::enable_if_is_not_B<D, R> [with D = A<main()::Z>::U; R = void; T = main()::Z]'
<stdin>:63:2:   required by substitution of 'template<class D> B<T>::enable_if_is_not_B<D> B<T>::operator()(const D&) const [with D = D; T = main()::Z] [with D = A<main()::Z>::U]'
<stdin>:83:7:   required from here
<stdin>:21:96: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, void>'
```

How to "export/import" the enabler from one class template to another?

Why SFINAE does not work?

Comment: If I add an initializer to `X const x;`, clang++3.4 compiles both versions.

Comment: clang++3.4 complains there has to be an initializer for a const object, I changed it to `X const x{};`. Then, it compiles both `#if 0` and `#if 1`.

Comment: Maybe this has to do with the immediate context in "Substitution Failure *in the immediate context* Is Not An Error"?

Comment: `# g++ --version
g++.exe (rev2, Built by MinGW-builds project) 4.8.0
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.`

Comment: Yes, same behaviour still in g++4.8.1. But as the behaviour is different between two compilers either one has a bug or it isn't precisely specified in the Standard. From what I know, the *immediate context* isn't precisely specified, and it might depend on the transparency of the alias templates whether it applies here.

Comment: Now I think, that I should use the `template< ... > ... = std::enable_if< ... >;` form instead of `template< ... > ... = typename std::enable_if< ... >::type`. But this leads to more verbose using of the enabler (`typename enabler< ... >::type` instead of `enabler< ... >`).

Comment: @DyP good investiagtion. Thanks. So, the answer depends on the compiler.

Comment: [Take a look at this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39c234d2d399e83e). I'm quite sure gcc handles the resolution of the alias templates differently than clang, and is somehow confused with the two layers of aliases.

Comment: I tried to clarify a bit the problem with the second layer of alias templates. If you don't like it, just roll back the edit. The term *export* in the context of templates, might be misleading, as there was an export feature for templates in the previous Standard.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the problem. Of course, I will accept your changes.

Comment: My proposal to use `template< ... > enabler = std::enable_if< ... >;` came to grief with error `template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use -ftemplate-depth= to increase the maximum)`. I believe that this is also an important case. Thus no ways to solve the problem.

Comment: Huh? Could you post a link to this version or add it to the question? The version I linked above works with g++4.8.1. Also, I just checked with a recent g++4.9 trunk, and it still has this behaviour.

Comment: Hmm, in my real-life example both cases leads to the same error (with depth exceedance).

Comment: `template< typename I, typename R = void >
    using enable_if_is_instruction_ = typename function_type::template enable_if_is_instruction< I, R >;` where is the recursion?

Comment: Could you post a complete example that allows me to replicate the problem?

Comment: It is complex library with dependencies (`boost` and Google Testing Framework) for Qt (Windows only). Do you really want?

Comment: Well I could at least have a look at it ;)

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/insituc/insituc/ (not shadow build (uncheck checkbox) and provide right paths to libraries)

Comment: `git pull` it (changes was introduced in one of last recent versions, so absent in public repository)

Comment: Done; will take some time though.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/insituc/insituc/commits/73fdac72d50e94218a0d4c822742db8266493b7f This version generates the same error, even if we rename the alias.

Comment: I now moved the `enable_if_is_instruction` directly in the template argument of `monitor::operator()`, and that seems to work. I can only imagine the infinite recursion is either due to a compiler bug, or instantiating `function_type` (the `function` template) or one of the template arguments somehow requires instantiating `monitor` (I didn't find anything, though).

Comment: Yes, I already moved too. But is ugly.