# different behaviour of enabler in different contexts in class templates

Tags: c++, sfinae, type-traits, class-template

Why the behaviour is so different? `#if 1` version successfully (that is weird) compiles and produces the expected output to *stdout*, but version with `#if 0` does not:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

#include <cstdlib>

template< typename T >
class X
{

    struct B {};

public :

    struct U : B {};

};

template< typename T >
struct Y
{

    using X_type = X< T >;

    template< typename D,
              typename = typename std::enable_if< std::is_base_of< typename X_type::B, D >::value >::type >
    void operator () (D const &) const
    {
        std::cout << "allowed only for derived from B" << std::endl;
    }

};

template< typename T >
struct Z
{

    using X_type = X< T >;

    template< typename D >
    auto
    operator () (D const &) const
    -> typename std::enable_if< std::is_base_of< typename X_type::B, D >::value >::type
    {
        std::cout << "allowed only for derived from B!" << std::endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
    using T = struct W; // not matters
    using X_type = X< T >;
    using U = typename X_type::U;
#if 0
    using V = Y< T >;
#else
    using V = Z< T >;
#endif
    V v;
    v(U());
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This generates an error (essentially **'B' is private** in accordance with my expectations (in fact) for both cases):

```
<stdin>: In function 'int main()':
<stdin>:60:10: error: no match for call to '(V {aka Z<main()::W>}) (U)'
<stdin>:34:8: note: candidate is:
<stdin>:41:5: note: template<class D> typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<typename X<T>::B, D>::value>::type Z<T>::operator()(const D&) const [with D = D; T = main()::W]
<stdin>:41:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<stdin>: In substitution of 'template<class D> typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<typename X<T>::B, D>::value>::type Z<T>::operator()(const D&) const [with D = D; T = main()::W] [with D = X<main()::W>::U]':
<stdin>:60:10:   required from here
<stdin>:10:12: error: 'struct X<main()::W>::B' is private
<stdin>:41:5: error: within this context
```

`g++ -v` output contains the following line:

```
gcc version 4.8.1 (rev3, Built by MinGW-builds project)
```

I expect that the `B` is not accessible at all from anywere except `X`.

The problem take place exceptionally only for the class templates, but not for pure classes (here we have two identical problems, because both variants do not have to be compiled, but they are compiled).

Comment: I expect that the `B` is not accessible at all from anywere except `X`.

Comment: I guess the reason is the default argument, it only gets evaluated if (and when) it is used.

Comment: Default unnamed argument used ("evaluated") in both cases, be sure. Try to call `v(0);` instead of `v(U());`.

Comment: Oops I was compiling with clang++3.4 again ;) where both versions fail.

Comment: @DyP And that's what I'll happily expect =).

Comment: With taking into account main provisions of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19378749/, for myself, I can conclude that `clang` project has overtaken `gcc` project.

Comment: In terms of conformance, probably. Maybe take a look [at this and the related bugs](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47346).

Comment: @DyP This is quite similar to the essence of the question. Thanks.

Comment: @DyP note, that **GCC** compiles both variants, if we works with the classes, not the class templates.