# Does SFINAE not apply here?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae, enable-if

I was writing something to use SFINAE to not generate a function under certain conditions.  When I use the meta code directly it works as expected, but when I use the code indirectly through another class, it fails to work as expected.

I thought that this was a VC++ thing, but looks like g++ also has this, so I'm wondering if there's some reason that SFINAE isn't being applied to this case.

The code is simple.  If the class used isn't the base class of a "collection class", then don't generate the function.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <type_traits>

#define USE_DIRECT 0
#define ENABLE 1

class A{};
class B{};
class C{};
class D{};
class collection1 : A, B, C {};
class collection2 : D {};

#if USE_DIRECT
template<typename X>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<X, collection1>::value, X>::type fn(X x)
{
    return X();
}

# if ENABLE
template<typename X>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<X, collection2>::value, X>::type fn(X x)
{
    return X();
}
# endif

#else // USE_DIRECT

template<typename X, typename COLLECTION>
struct enable_if_is_base_of
{
    static const int value = std::is_base_of<X, COLLECTION>::value;
    typedef typename std::enable_if<value, X>::type type;
};

template<typename X>
typename enable_if_is_base_of<X, collection1>::type fn(X x)
{
    return X();
}

# if ENABLE
template<typename X>
typename enable_if_is_base_of<X, collection2>::type fn(X x)
{
    return X();
}
# endif
#endif // USE_DIRECT

int main()
{
    fn(A());
    fn(B());
    fn(C());
    fn(D());

   return 0;
}
```

If I set USE_DIRECT to 1 and ENABLE to 0, then it fails to compile as there is no function `fn` that takes a parameter `D`.  Setting ENABLE to 1 will stop that error from occurring.

However, if I set USE_DIRECT to 0 and ENABLE to 0, it will fail with different error messages but for the same case, there is no `fn` that takes parameter `D`. Setting ENABLE to 1 however will cause a failure for all 4 function calls.

For your convience, here is the code in an online compiler: http://goo.gl/CQcXHr

Can someone explain what is happening here and why?

This looks like it may be related to [Alias templates used in SFINAE lead to a hard error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19378749/alias-templates-used-in-sfinae-lead-to-a-hard-error), but no one has answered that either.

For reference, here are the errors that were generated by g++:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'struct enable_if_is_base_of<A, collection2>':                                                                   
main.cpp:45:53:   required by substitution of 'template<class X> typename enable_if_is_base_of<X, collection2>::type fn(X) [with X = A]'       
main.cpp:54:8:   required from here                                                                                                            
main.cpp:34:82: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, A>'                                                               
  typedef typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<X, COLLECTION>::value, X>::type type;                                                        
                                                                                  ^                                                            
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'struct enable_if_is_base_of<B, collection2>':                                                                   
main.cpp:45:53:   required by substitution of 'template<class X> typename enable_if_is_base_of<X, collection2>::type fn(X) [with X = B]'       
main.cpp:55:8:   required from here                                                                                                            
main.cpp:34:82: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, B>'                                                               
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'struct enable_if_is_base_of<C, collection2>':                                                                   
main.cpp:45:53:   required by substitution of 'template<class X> typename enable_if_is_base_of<X, collection2>::type fn(X) [with X = C]'       
main.cpp:56:8:   required from here                                                                                                            
main.cpp:34:82: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, C>'                                                               
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'struct enable_if_is_base_of<D, collection1>':                                                                   
main.cpp:38:53:   required by substitution of 'template<class X> typename enable_if_is_base_of<X, collection1>::type fn(X) [with X = D]'       
main.cpp:57:8:   required from here                                                                                                            
main.cpp:34:82: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, D>'
```

Comment: Uh, in your indirect case, as the name indicates, the error is not in the direct context, so it is a true error...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only a substitution that takes place in an *immediate context* may result in a deduction failure:

§14.8.2 [temp.deduct]/p8

> Only invalid types and expressions in the immediate context of the function type and
>   its template parameter types can result in a deduction failure. [ *Note*: The evaluation of the substituted types
>   and expressions can result in side effects **such as the instantiation of class template specializations** and/or
>   function template specializations, the generation of implicitly-defined functions, etc. **Such side effects are
>   not in the “immediate context” and can result in the program being ill-formed.** — *end note* ]

The signature of `fn` requires a full declaration of `enable_if_is_base`'s specialization to exist:

§14.7.1 [temp.inst]/p1

> Unless a class template specialization has been explicitly instantiated (14.7.2) or explicitly specialized (14.7.3),
>   the class template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context
>   that requires a completely-defined object type or when the completeness of the class type affects the semantics
>   of the program.

The compiler fails to generate the specialization of:

```
template<typename X, typename COLLECTION>
struct enable_if_is_base_of
{
    static const int value = std::is_base_of<X, COLLECTION>::value;
    typedef typename std::enable_if<value, X>::type type;
};
```

because the substitution of `typename std::enable_if<value, X>::type` results in a missing type if `value` evaluates to `false`, which is not in an immediate context.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the answer that I'm looking for.  I just am having trouble understanding it. o.O

Comment: I now understand with the help of [@BenVoigt](http://stackoverflow.com/users/103167/ben-voigt) what this means.  As it references the standard though, I'm going to mark yours as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As already answered your SFINAE scheme can't work. However, you could use the following not so pretty solution to achieve what you probably want:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

class A{};
class B{};
class C{};
class D{};
class collection1 : A, B, C {};
class collection2 : D {};

template<typename X, class Enable = void>
struct enable_if_is_base_of;

template<typename X>
struct enable_if_is_base_of<X, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<X, collection1>::value>::type> {
  static X fn(X x) {
    (void) x;
    std::cout << "collection1" << std::endl;
    return X();
  }
};

template<typename X>
struct enable_if_is_base_of<X, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<X, collection2>::value>::type> {
  static X fn(X x) {
    (void) x;
    std::cout << "collection2" << std::endl;
    return X();
  }
};

int main() {
  enable_if_is_base_of<A>::fn(A());
  enable_if_is_base_of<B>::fn(B());
  enable_if_is_base_of<C>::fn(C());
  enable_if_is_base_of<D>::fn(D());
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7871805b4a0aa508)

Comment: Yeah, that's actually going the wrong way.  I was trying to simplify the reading of the code.  This actually makes this harder to read, and makes the function a member function instead of a pure one.  It's interesting though.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that if the type doesn't exist, the typedef isn't skipped, it is an error.

Solution: no typedef

```
template<typename X, typename COLLECTION>
struct enable_if_is_base_of : std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<X, COLLECTION>::value, X>
{};
```

Now the `type` member exists (via inheritance) if and only if it exists within the `enable_if` instantiation.

Comment: I like this solution.  It is very simple.  I just don't understand why the type doesn't exist is a problem.  I thought that was the whole point of this.  If no type, then substitution failure.  Substitution Failure Is Not An Error, so move on.

Comment: Oh, I get it.  The `std::is_base_of<X, COLLECTION>::value` evaluates to *nothing* so results in `typedef type` which is malformed, which results in the class not existing.  Since it doesn't exist, it can not have a member named *type*. Having it inherit makes the code well formed in both contexts (if it is a base or not), so SFINAE can then be applied.

Comment: @Adrian: Not quite.  `is_base_of` is either `true_type` or `false_type`, and both define `value`.  Which is good, since SFINAE doesn't happen in the base class list either.  You end up inheriting from `std::enable_if<false>`, which has no member named `type`, exactly as you need.  SFINAE only works to remove template functions from a candidate list during overload resolution.  It doesn't apply to typedefs, base class lists, etc.

Comment: Which is what `§14.8.2 [temp.deduct]/p8` is referring to.  Right?

Comment: @Adrian: Yes, that's a different way of saying the same thing.